# Tkinter and Python list

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am creating a program which generates a random list of songs, and has a function such that if a user wants to save a song from the random generated list, the user should click the button next to it. Then the user can print the songs he/she saved on a new window, but the function for that in my code seems to only print the saved songs in the terminal and I only get empty window. How can I implement this correctly?

This the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import random


root = Tk()
root.title('UMIND')
root.geometry('')

a = [
    'Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade',
    'All Too Well - Taylor Swift',
    'Gravity - Sara Bareilles',
    'Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan',
    'Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance',
    'Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift',
    'Champagne - Taylor Swift',
    'Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade',
    'Blame It On The Rain - He Is We',
    'Sad Song - We The Kings',
    'Give It All - He Is We',
    'Heavy - Linkin Park',
    'Ride - Twenty One Pilot',
    'One more light - Linkin Park',
    'Ride Home - Ben and Ben',
    'Leaves - Ben and Ben',
    'Fall - Ben and Ben',
    'Maybe the night - Ben and Ben',
    'Sunrise - Ben and Ben'
]


def show():
    global alist
    alist = []
    if genre.get() == 'Favorite':
        # alist.clear()
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title('Your Playlist')
        for i, title in enumerate(random.sample(a, k=10)):
            myLabel = Label(top, text=title, font='times 12', anchor=W)
            myLabel.grid(column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E, row=i)

            Button(top,
                   text=str(i + 1) + ".",
                   border=5,
                   padx=5,
                   pady=5,
                   command=lambda title=title: alist.append(title)
                   ).grid(column=0, row=i)
        btn2 = Button(top, text='close window', command=top.destroy).grid(row=12, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=W + E)


def my_playlist():
    global alist
    blist = []
    global myLabel
    for song in alist:
        if song not in alist:
            blist.append(song)

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title('Your Playlist')
    for i, title in enumerate(blist):
        myLabel = Label(top, text=title, font='times 12', anchor=W)
        myLabel.grid(column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E, row=i)

    print(alist)

options = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Favorite"
]
genre = StringVar()
genre.set('From what genre?')


drop = OptionMenu(root, genre, *options)
drop.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=20, ipady=10, padx=15, pady=15)
generate_btn = Button(root, text="Generate Playlist", command=show).grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=30, ipady=10, padx=15,
                                                                         pady=15)

playlist_btn = Button(root, text="My Playlist", command=my_playlist).grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=30, ipady=10,
                                                                         padx=15, pady=15)

Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
row_con = [ drop, generate_btn, playlist_btn]
row_num = 0
for row in row_con:
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, row_num, weight=1)
    row_num += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your code is long - where do you try to display  it in other window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing all your problem is because you use silimar names of variables `alist` and `blist` and finally you used wrong list in code

```
for song in alist:
    if song not in alist:   # <-- should be `blist`
        blist.append(song)
```

Should be

```
for song in alist:
    if song not in blist:   # <-- should be `blist`
        blist.append(song)
```

In your version you get from `alist` and compare with the same `alist` so it always gives `False` and it never add to `blist`

---

Eventually you could use `set()` to recognize new titles.

---

But I think you have other problem - you try to add to `blist` only new items but before `for`-loop you use

```
blist = []
```

so your list empty and there is no need to check what to move to `blist` because you can move everthing

```
blist = alist
```

If you want to keep previous items then you shouldn't assing `blist = []` and you should keep it as global list.

---

**EDIT**

My full version with other changes: better names for funtions and variables, all function before rest of code, etc.

[PEP 8 -- Style Guid for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random

# --- functions ---

def show_generated_list():
    global generated_list
    
    generated_list = []
    
    if genre.get() == 'Favorite':
    
        # generated_list.clear()
        top = tk.Toplevel()
        top.title('Your Playlist')
        
        for i, title in enumerate(random.sample(a, k=10)):
        
            my_label = tk.Label(top, text=title, font='times 12', anchor='w')  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variales
            my_label.grid(column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='we', row=i)

            tk.Button(top,
                   text=str(i+1) + ".",
                   border=5,
                   padx=5,
                   pady=5,
                   command=lambda title=title: generated_list.append(title)
                   ).grid(column=0, row=i)
                   
        tk.Button(top, text='close window', command=top.destroy).grid(row=12, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='we')


def show_my_playlist():  # verb for function name, noun for variable
    global generated_list    # PEP8: all `global` at the beginning
    #global my_label # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variales  # you don't need it
    
    for song in generated_list:
        if song not in my_playlist:
            my_playlist.append(song)

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title('Your Playlist')
    
    for i, title in enumerate(my_playlist):
        my_label = tk.Label(top, text=title, font='times 12', anchor='w')
        my_label.grid(column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='we', row=i)

    print(generated_list)

# --- main ---

# - data -

a = [
    'Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade',
    'All Too Well - Taylor Swift',
    'Gravity - Sara Bareilles',
    'Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan',
    'Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance',
    'Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift',
    'Champagne - Taylor Swift',
    'Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade',
    'Blame It On The Rain - He Is We',
    'Sad Song - We The Kings',
    'Give It All - He Is We',
    'Heavy - Linkin Park',
    'Ride - Twenty One Pilot',
    'One more light - Linkin Park',
    'Ride Home - Ben and Ben',
    'Leaves - Ben and Ben',
    'Fall - Ben and Ben',
    'Maybe the night - Ben and Ben',
    'Sunrise - Ben and Ben'
]

options = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Favorite"
]

generated_list = []  # created at start to make sure it always exists
my_playlist = []     # created at start to make sure it always exists
    
- gui -

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('UMIND')
#root.geometry('')  # empty geometry is useless

genre = tk.StringVar()
genre.set('From what genre?')

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, genre, *options)
drop.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=20, ipady=10, padx=15, pady=15)

generate_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Generate Playlist", command=show_generated_list)
generate_btn.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=30, ipady=10, padx=15, pady=15)

playlist_btn = tk.Button(root, text="My Playlist", command=show_my_playlist)
playlist_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=30, ipady=10, padx=15, pady=15)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

row_con = [drop, generate_btn, playlist_btn]

for row_num in range(len(row_con)):
    root.rowconfigure(row_num, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would I retain the contents or the items of my_playlist, because when I rerun the program my_playlist resets and  loses its contents or items that were previously added?

Comment: my version keeps previous content. I create `my_playlist = []` only at start and later I don't use `my_playlist = []` in function `show_my_playlist`

Comment: when I close the program then open and run it again, and click My Playlist button it only returns an empty window

Comment: now I see what is your problem. Python will not keep it for you - like in any other program (ie. Word, Excel) you have to save it on disk and read it again when you restart program. You may use normal `txt` file or something more useful like `csv` file or `json` file or module `pickle`

Comment: I will try one of those, because I just tried using sqlite but I can not comprehend it yet

Comment: `SQLite` needs much more work - but it can be very useful when you want to filter data and use complex searching.